# Number of positive integer solutions of a equation system with restrictions.

Tags: combinatorics

The question is how many possible solutions there are for a equation system subject to the condition that $1 \leq x_1 + y_1$, $1 \leq x_2 + y_2$, $1 \leq x_r + y_r$ where $x_i$ and $y_i$ are non-negative integers.

The system is   $$x_1 + x_2 + \ldots + x_r = n.$$
$$y_1 + y_2 + \ldots + y_r = n.$$

I want to do it by the inclusion-exclusion principle but i can't find a way to pose a initial equation.
After that i would suppose $ 1 - y_1 > x_1 $ and try to introduce it in one of those equations.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If $x_i,y_i$ are **positive** integers the conditions $x_i+y_i\ge1$ are always fulfilled. Therefore you can simply multiply the numbers of solutions for each equation.

Comment: Feeding on the previous comment, see this [Stars and Bars article](https://brilliant.org/wiki/integer-equations-star-and-bars/).  Note that (for example) the number of positive integer solutions to $$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_r = n$$ is the same as the number of **non-negative** integer solutions to $$w_1 + w_2 + \cdots + w_r = (n-r).$$

Comment: Ok thanks; and what would I have to do if integers can be non-positive??

Comment: @Mrshowman__ If you want to change the question, you should edit the question itself.

Comment: You should not confuse non-positive integers with non-negative.

Comment: My bad, sorry...

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please accept $\checkmark$ and upvote if you want to. Otherwise feel free to ask for clarification in comments below the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a simpler solution, but you can certainly run this by inclusion-exclusion on a reducing $r$.

I'm thinking of this as being like deployment of $n$ infantry and $n$ artillery into a position with $r$ locations, where you cannot leave any gap in the line. Without the gap restriction we can easily see this is two cases of [stars-and-bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) for $\binom{n+r-1}{n}^2$

A gap in both categories ($x_i+y_i=0$) would correspond to a deployment into $r{-}1$ positions. The gap can occur in $\binom r1=r$ locations of course. Then we have to account for overcounting the case of $2$ gaps, etc., giving

$$\sum_{k =0}^{r-1}(-1)^k\binom{r}{k}\binom{n+r-1-k}{n}^2  $$

Comment: Hi, the explanation is really good, but i can't understand the final formula. I mean i don't understand why the gap can occur in those locations and why the overcountinig give this formula.

Comment: The inclusion-exclusion proceeds with alternating signs for over counting and undercounting, for a reducing number of positions selected in different ways from the original set.